# Howto use protobuf-net to serialize WCF Faults

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, protobuf-net, fault

I was thinking when I apply the `ProtoEndpointbehavior` to an WCF `ServiceEndpoint` (of course client and server side) all dataobjects "known" by protobuf-net are serailized by protobuf-net.

```
    public static void ApplyProtoBufEndPointBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoEndpointBehavior());
    }
```

Yesterday I learned that this is not true.

When throwing a `FaultException<TDetail>` always the DataContractSerializer is used. So far I did not even realize this because all my faults consisted of .net standard types only.

But yesterday I tried to send one an object of my own datatype with a custom fault. I took me quite a while what was going...

How can I teach WCF to serialize faults with protobuf-net as well?

We are using .NET 4.0 and net.tcp binding.

Comment: Reality is that I haven't touched WCF in a long time; I *don't know* what to do here. If you have ideas...

Comment: @MarcGravell I had quite a problem because all my dataobjects were just decorated with protobuf attributes. And the de/serialization logic is quite tricky so going for the DataContractSerializer was not an option. We ended up serializing the dataobject beforehand to a byte[]...